# Deleting a User from a Conversation with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a `Conversation` table which has a list of `Users` as a column, as well as a list of `Messages` and some other data.

I am looking to **remove** a `User` from the `Conversation` table, without deleting the `User` or `Conversation` altogether as they might be used elsewhere.

I am not sure how to do this...

I wish to do this using a **Linq** query but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to create the query.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
[HttpPut]
//[ResponseType(typeof(Conversation))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RemoveUserFromGroup(String key, User user)
{
    Conversation conver = await db.Conversations.FindAsync(key);

    if (conver == null)
    {
            return NotFound();
    }

    IEnumerable<User> del = from d in conver.Users
                            where d.Email == user.Email
                            select d;

    conver.Users.Remove(del);    // ERROR ON THIS LINE AT "del"

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(conver);
}
```

This piece of code doesn't do what I want it to however

`Conversation` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Conversation
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ConversationName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Administrator { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public Conversation()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}
```

`User` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Admin { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Conversations = new HashSet<Conversation>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see a sample of your code please?

Comment: If it has a nullable key i.e. it's not a required relationship then you can simply load the entity and null the UserID property then save the entity and the user will be removed. It would help if you could post your code.

Comment: @JamesDev The relationship is not a required one.. So I could just retrieve the User and set its Email(PK) to be null?

Comment: Yes but please post your entity class for Conversation and User and any foreign key mappings.

Comment: This code removes the *conversation*. You should remove the *user* from the conversation's `Users` collection.

Comment: I have updated the linq query but it still is not right. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RemoveUserFromGroup(String key, [FromBody]User user)
{
    Conversation conver = await db.Conversations.FindAsync(key);
    if (conver == null)
    {
          return NotFound();
    }

    IEnumerable<User> del = from d in conver.Users
                            where d.Email == user.Email
                            select d;

    conver.Users.Remove(del.ToList()[0]);

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(conver);
}
```

This solution fixed the problem! It will remove a user from a specified User from a specified group appropriately.